# Find any variable that is undefined and hide from url string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a URL string from form inputs to look something similar to this:

```
api/search/127879/11-28-2013/7/2/undefined/undefined/undefined/LGW/null
```

How would i find any or all variables that === to undefined and then remove from these from the string above?

Comment: can you share the script

Comment: How are you generating string? Check before that, and if undefined, don't append it

Comment: I can ask a better questions if mark downs are explained on stackoverflow.

Comment: is that work for you ??

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to chage logic of building url than just make use of replace function of javascript

```
var str = "api/search/127879/11-28-2013/7/2/undefined/undefined/undefined/LGW/null"; 
var res = str.replace(/undefined\//gi,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating string yourself, then check before appending it to urlString.

If you get the string from server, then do this:

```
var finalUrl = "";
var urlStr= "api/search/127879/11-28-2013/7/2/undefined/undefined/undefined/LGW/null";
var urlArray = urlStr.split('/');
for (i = 0, i = urlArray.length; i ++) {
    if(urlArray[i] === undefined)
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        finalUrl += urlArray[i];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.